# Advanced Custom Fields Pro - need unique field groups for every page?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am using ACF pro and I am questioning something as I move through some of these unique pages on my website. 
Example - 3 portfolio pages, each with the same markup/layout. If I want to use ACF on these pages do I really have to create 3 unique wordpress php templates, and 3 sets of field groups with unique field names?

So (a simplified example, my pages have about 20 fields each):

```
template_one.php // "hero_image_1" // "hero_title_1"

template_two.php // "hero_image_2" // "hero_title_2"

template_three.php // "hero_image_3" // "hero_title_3"
```

and then 3 separate field groups with these unique field names?

I just feel like there should be more efficiencies that I am just not seeing here.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

No. You don't need 3 different ACF groups.

You need one group applied to the three different templates.

Beneath the area where you add fields is a "Location" box where you set when to show these fields.

Adjust those settings so that your field group displays on all the relevant templates.

[image: Selecting different page templates]

Comment: Thank you Nick - appreciate the reply, Well ,i do that currently. But have run into issues. Not sure how the database differentiates the fields, between pages, since it need to be unique content (but same field layout) if that makes sense. When I saw this post - it confused me further...

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/different-values-for-same-field-groups-on-different-options-pages/

Comment: So just to be sure - 
hero_image_1 (pony)

hero_image_two (kitten) 

hero_image_3 (puppy) 

Could work as you mentioned above, with the same field group?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want hero_image and hero_title in your ACF group. In each template you'll get_field('hero_image') to pull the image you've set in the back end.

Comment: so using the came ACF field group, I can have unique images on the 3 different pages? Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't see your link to the forum topic before. That's referring to when you add your acf fields to an options page. Since you're adding your fields to pages or templates you don't have to worry about the issue they're talking about.